# need help in HTML::TagFilter, getting rid of style tag content

Tags: html, perl

I have a filter written in perl looks like this

```
my $tf = HTML::TagFilter->new(
            allow => {
                img => { src => [] },
                b   => { all => [] },
                i   => { all => [] },
                em  => { all => [] },
                u   => { all => [] },
                s   => { all => [] },
            },
            strip_comments      => 1,
            skip_xss_protection => 1,
        );
```

now when I pass html like this

```
<html>
<head>
<style><!--
..hmmessage P
{
margin:0px=3B
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 12pt=3B
font-family:Calibri
}
--></style></head>
<body class=3D'hmmessage'><div dir=3D'ltr'>Message content here! =
</div></body>
</html>
```

the output is

```
<!--..hmmessage P{margin:0px;padding:0px}body.hmmessage{font-size: 12pt;font-family:Calibri}-->Message content here
```

if you look at the output you find that the content of the style tag  still exist, I don't know why?, so can any one tells me why the style tag content still exists after passing through the filter?

Comment: You have problems in your HTML, these `=3D` are quoted-printable encoded for `=`. You must decode your email first! Use [MIME::QuotedPrint](http://p3rl.org/MIME::QuotedPrint) or a high-level MIME parsing toolkit such as [Courriel](http://p3rl.org/Courriel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an undocumented "feature" of `HTML::TagFilter` which is a result of sublassing [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser). The latter interprets `<style>` and `<script>` tag contents as CDATA and parses them by default, ignoring allowed and denied tags:

> The script and style tags will always nest properly since their content is parsed in CDATA mode.

[*Source*](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser#p-ignore_elements-tags)

To solve this problem just invoke

```
$tf->ignore_elements('style');
```

before invoking parse method on your HTML - it'll ignore style tag and do what you want. Note that in your example code, if you substtute `style` with `foo`, there won't be any comment printed.